# How to query on a three mysql joined table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have three mysql table:

1. *page_category* table

```
    CREATE TABLE `page_category` (
      `id_page` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `search_here` TEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_page`),
      FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`search_here`)
    ) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

*page_category* table contains more than 2 million rows of data.

1. *user_page* table

```
    CREATE TABLE `user_page` (
      `user_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `id_page` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`id_page`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

*user_page* table contains more than 10 million rows of data.

1. *user_relationship* table

```
    CREATE TABLE `user_relationship` (
      `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `me` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `friend` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `me_friend` (`me`,`friend`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=7517967 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

*user_relationship* table contains more than 1 million rows of data.

I do a query:

```
SELECT a.id_page AS ids, b.user_id, 
a.name AS nama, c.me, 
COUNT(c.me) AS nfriend, 
GROUP_CONCAT(b.user_id SEPARATOR ',') AS friendlist
FROM
page_category a
LEFT JOIN user_page b
ON a.id_page = b.id_page
LEFT JOIN user_relationship c
ON
b.user_id = c.friend
WHERE
c.me='12' AND
MATCH(a.search_here) AGAINST('+book' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

results are shown in a very long time. am I wrong on writing the query?

Comment: add indexes on columns that you use in JOIN and WHERE clauses

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proper indexing as well as you need to make query so that it has less temp. You can change order of join and explain it to debug your query to ger the best one.